# Include symbols in <cword>

Tags: vimscript

`expand(<cword>)` gives me the word under the cursor, but it excludes symbols such as `@` or `.`. For example, if I call it at the end of `@word`, it will get me `word` and exclude the `@`.

Is there a way that I could include symbols as part of the current word?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The characters that are included in a Vim `word` are set by the `'iskeyword'` option. See

```
:help <word>
:help word
:help 'iskeyword'
```

To add another character to this set, such as `.`, execute the following:

```
:set iskeyword+=.
```

See

```
:help :set+=
```

Note that the character `@` is special, so it has be added like this:

```
:set iskeyword+=@-@
```

See

```
:help 'isfname'
```

Comment: `@-@`? Is  that Bram's way of showing he's mad at use for making `@` part of words?

Comment: Note that there are side effects to changing `iskeyword`. For example, if you add `@` to `iskeyword`, the standard word motion command (`w`) will also move across e.g. `@word @otherword`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `expand(<cWORD>)`.

From [`:help :<cWORD>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3a%3ccWORD%3e):

> `<cWORD>`    is replaced with the WORD under the cursor (see `WORD`)

and from [`:help WORD`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#WORD):

> A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
>   space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
>
> A sequence of folded lines is counted for one word of a single character.
>   "w" and "W", "e" and "E" move to the start/end of the first word or WORD after
>   a range of folded lines.  "b" and "B" move to the start of the first word or
>   WORD before the fold.

Comment: Thanks, @Carpetsmoker! I didn't have the time to expand my answer until now.

Comment: `viW`, `ciW`, `diW`, `yiW` also will works like `<cWORD>` against `<cword>`